# Abaqus python macro function with for loop - 'unexpected indent'

Tags: python-2.7, indentation, abaqus

I'm trying to write a simple macro with a for loop but keep getting this error about indentation. I've seen several threads about this and feel certain my indentation is fine so I'm not sure what's wrong. Here it is:

```
# -*- coding: mbcs -*-
# Do not delete the following import lines
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import __main__

def ex():
    import section
    #...more imports
    import connectorBehavior

    a = mdb.models['Model'].rootAssembly
    r1 = a.referencePoints
    for i in range(0,9):
        print(r1(i))
```

And the error it returns is

```
IndentationError: ('unexpected indent', ('C:\\Users\\user\\abaqusMacros.py', 14, 1, '\tfor i in range(0,9):\n'))
```

Do I need to change the indentation? Thank you.

Comment: I don't get this error. Try deleting the preceding whitespace and retabbing the lines around the `for` loop

Comment: Are you mixing tab characters and spaces in your text editor?  4 spaces will look the same as one tab, but the interpreter will throw an error if there is inconsistent use of tabs and spaces.

Comment: Yep, Notepad++ was doing a tab character while 4 spaces are required, thank you!